# How to get the ID of a nested div to build a var with

Tags: jquery, var

I'm trying to build a var to be used in a function. The function needs to run on multiple div's that have separate ID's. Essentially, the var would be grabbing the ID of each div and running the function based on that. I just can't get it working correctly.

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="group">
    <div id="element1" class="element">Stuff</div>
    <div id="element2" class="element">Stuff</div>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery var "attempt" :)

```
var elementVar = $('.group').find('.element')this.attr('id');
```

So essentially, will be ran like the following, so that the function runs on each div id

```
$(elementVar).click(function(){ ...
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.group .element').click(function(){
id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

but i recommend something like this. It gives you the clean data.

```
<div id="element2" class="element" data-id="2">Stuff</div>
$('.group .element').click(function(){
id = $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.group div.element').click(function() {
   $(this).....;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just simple

```
$('.element').click(function(){
   id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
$(".group").children().each(function(){});
```

This gets all the children of the div with class `group` and applies the function within the `each()` jQuery function to them.

So to trigger a function on click:

```
$(".group").children().each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    // click event here
  });
});
```

Also, as long as all the divs will have classes, just select the class:

```
$(".element").each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    // click event here
  });
});
```

But you probably only added classes so your method would work. If you're not going to add classes, then the first method is your best option.

More on `children();` [here](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and more on `each();` [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/).